# No POST-Data from Ajax in Django

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I want to post a array of data in AJAX to a Django-Site. 
Code from Javascript:

```
var arr = {};
arr["first"] = "first";
arr["second"] = "second";
arr["third"] = "third";
var success = ""
    var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
     var rawtext = xmlhttp.responseText;

     document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML= jsonToHTMLTable(rawtext);
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","/AJAX?modus=create");  
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
alert(JSON.stringify(arr));
xmlhttp.send({data:JSON.stringify(arr)});
```

But when i debug (with Eclipse) i don't see an array or other useful fields.

This is the code from django:

```
def AJAX(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    method = request.REQUEST.get("modus","")
    if method == 'create':
        test = request.POST['data']
```

More informations
Traceback from Django-Debug

```
Environment:
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/AJAX?modus=create
Django Version: 1.6.5
Python Version: 3.4.1
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')
Traceback:
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  112. response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Lee\web\reportingTool\ReportingTool\TempDosage\views.py" in AJAX
14. test = request.POST['data']
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py" in __getitem__
301.             raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /AJAX
Exception Value: "'data'"
```

How can I access to my data?

Comment: Can you please paste the code of your View. Generally it is located in: `request.POST` but this may vary

Comment: Do you have `DEBUG=True` in settings.py? Which version of Django you're using? What does variable `test` contain? Did you debug request.POST? What is the Server response? Please provide more information, it is your desire to get help.

Comment: Yes Debug is on true and I am using the 1.6.5 version. The variable test contains noting. It should countain the array (JSON-Format). 
The debug-log: 
    MultiValueDictKeyError at /AJAX
    "'data'"

Comment: Do you seriously need to support IE *5* in your Javascript?

Comment: No. I copy & paste this part

Comment: The full traceback of "MultiValueDictKeyError at /AJAX" will be fine. (E.g. at https://dpaste.de/)

Comment: I made a little test:
I used a plugin called (HttpRequester) and send the data to the django server. Now in the request attribute their is another attribute called body with the json-string. 
Could it be that the javascript part is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the part wich was wrong (Javascript):

Here is the new JavascriptPart (which works for me):

```
var arr = {};
arr["first"] = "first";
arr["second"] = "second";
arr["third"] = "third";
var success = ""
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/AJAX?modus=create",
data: {"data": JSON.stringify(arr)},
success: success,
dataType: "application/json",
headers: {"X-CSRFToken": getCookie('csrftoken')}
});
```

And this is the django-part (view):

```
def AJAX(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
      method = request.REQUEST.get("modus","")
      if method == 'create':
          data = request.POST.get('data');
```